# kafka zookeeper - server start issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, messagebroker

I am new to Kafka and today I installed kafka and tried to start the zookeeper and kafka server using the below command.
**bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties**

But I am getting this error. Can someone help me on this
*ver (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2022-12-01 10:43:14,624] INFO Refusing session request for client /xxx.xxx.x.x:39796 as it has seen zxid 0x1600000086 our last zxid is 0x43 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2022-12-01 10:43:14,866] INFO Refusing session request for client /xxx.xxx.x.x:33924 as it has seen zxid 0x16000000e0 our last zxid is 0x43 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These commands assume that you are in the root directory of your Kafka installation. If you installed Kafka in a different directory, you will need to adjust the path to the `bin` directory accordingly.

It's also possible that Zookeeper server is already running on you system and is using the same port that you are trying to start the server on. Another possibility `config/zookeeper.properties` file is missing or is not readable by the user that you are running the zookeeper server as.

Comment: Thanks Adeeb Abdul.. I will check in those aspects